# How can I avoid duplicating class names in my replacement function?

Tags: javascript, html

This question follows on from this question:
[Keep font ligatures and have tighter letter-spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380337/keep-font-ligatures-and-have-tighter-letter-spacing/77392408#77392408)

I want to be able to find all ligatures ["fi", "fl", "ffi", "ffl", "fj", "ffj", "ff"] in my `<h1>` headings. Then wrap these characters in a `<span>` element with one class name.

The following code adds two class names. Can the code be simplified as I only want to add one class name? If the code can not be simplified, how do I only add the class name 'ligature'?

```
// add font-family classes
let ligatures = ["fi", "fl", "ffi", "ffl", "fj", "ffj", "ff"];
let ligatureEls = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
ligatureEls.forEach((el) => {
  highlightText(el, ligatures, "highlight ligature");
});

function highlightText(el, substrings, classNames = "highlight") {
  substrings.forEach((substring) => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(${substring})`, "gi");
    el.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
      if (childNode.nodeValue && regex.test(childNode.nodeValue)) {
        childNode.parentNode.innerHTML = childNode.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(
          regex,
          `<span class="${classNames}">${substring}</span>`
        );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the helpful answer below, I have the following code and two questions:

```
// add 'glyph' class to ligatures

let ligatures = ["fi", "fl", "ffi", "ffl", "fj", "ffj", "ff"];
// select ligatures within h1 element. Other elements can be added by seperating them with a comma?
highlightLigatures(document.querySelectorAll("h1"), ligatures);

function highlightLigatures(elements, substrings) {
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    highlightText(el, substrings, "glyph");
  });
}

// should classNames = "glyph" rather than "highlight"?
function highlightText(el, substrings, classNames = "highlight") {
  substrings.forEach((substring) => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(${substring})`, "gi");
    el.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
      if (childNode.nodeValue && regex.test(childNode.nodeValue)) {
        childNode.parentNode.innerHTML = childNode.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(
          regex,
          `<span class="${classNames}">${substring}</span>`
        );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Just give it a try and do some research on how JS functions and default parameters work. You can use any class names you want. The main reason I opted for a generic class name as "highlight" was the fact `highlightText()` is not specific to to the ligature replacement  - you can use it for any search term highlighting as well. Besides, the class name is irrelevant unless you apply properties to this class (e.g letter-spacing:0). Semantically glyph doesn't make much sense since you're wrapping multiple characters in a span - but that's also not relevant =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change the call to `highlightText` to only supply one class name:

```js
highlightText(el, ligatures, "ligature");
```

This is what the `classNames` parameter of `highlightText` means. It's default value is "highlight" but you can of course use any class you want (or multiple, as you have already tried out).
This makes `highlightText` general-use, which you might want to use with other texts and classes.

Also see [JavaScript functions - default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

---

You could add a function, which always adds the `ligature` class for you. It will not really reduce the code, as you're adding another function. But the source code will read more intuitively, especially if you re-use this throughout the code.

```js
// add font-family classes
let ligatures = ["fi", "fl", "ffi", "ffl", "fj", "ffj", "ff"];
highlightLigatures(document.querySelectorAll("h1"), ligatures);

function highlightLigatures(elements, substrings) {
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    highlightText(el, substrings, "ligature");
  });
}

function highlightText(el, substrings, classNames = "highlight") {
  substrings.forEach((substring) => {
    let regex = new RegExp(`(${substring})`, "gi");
    el.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
      if (childNode.nodeValue && regex.test(childNode.nodeValue)) {
        childNode.parentNode.innerHTML = childNode.parentNode.innerHTML.replace(
          regex,
          `<span class="${classNames}">${substring}</span>`
        );
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I suspect you want to use the same ligatures on maybe other elements as well. You can change the selector or call the method multiple times with different elements.

This is more of a subjective idea, it depends on your goals in terms of reusability or being a one-time thing you don't look at again.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question with some new questions. I'm afraid I can't read JavaScript so I'm struggle to see what is happening.

Comment: In general you would post follow-up questions as a separate questions. But I'll quickly answer here: 1. Yes you can use multiple selectors with a `,`. 2. `classNames = "highlight"` is just the default class name. If you call the function with a value for "classNames" this overrides the default value. For example above with `highlightText(el, substrings, "glyph");`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Which is correct 1. function highlightText(el, substrings, classNames = "glyph") or 2. function highlightText(el, substrings, classNames = "highlight")?

Comment: I want to add the class glyph to the span that wraps the selected characters

Comment: Read about [JavaScript functions - default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). Functions can have a default value for a parameter, but if you call the function with a different value for that parameter it will be used instead of the default.